# Azure Pipelines. Copy Files Task with multiple contents

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to publish an artifact in AzurePipelines and I want to copy only required files to `StagingDirectory`.

I have files to copy from the same parent folder but in different subdirectories. I have tried to add multiple contents to `CopyFiles@2` task but it doesn't work. The task log shows the message `found 0 files`.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    Contents: |
      $(projWinConsoles)\bin\Release\**
      $(projWinConsoles)\**\*.ico
    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WPF
```

Instead of that I have added two separate tasks and it's working. Does `CopyFiles@2` task admit multiple line contents? The docs suggest that it is supported.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    Contents: $(projWinConsoles)\bin\Release\**
    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WPF

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    Contents: $(projWinConsoles)\**\*.ico
    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WPF
```

Comment: The documentation clearly states that the case you show is possible. Could you be more specific when you say the first method "doesn't work"? It does not copy the files or shows an error?

Comment: The task is completed without errors but no files are copied. I have added the log message in the question (found 0 files)

Comment: I'm nervous with those backslashes. Several paths are joined in the "Contents" key. The problem *may* be so simple as that the file specifying the pipeline has `'\n'` endings instead of `'\r\n'` endings, as expected by Windows (or the other way around), so that the separation of the different routes doesn't work and don' get interpreted well... :( Other than that, you can file an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I running the same task definition in Windows Agent, it can work as expected.

[image]

And I can reproduce the same issue when using the Linux agent.

[image]

Refer to this doc: [CopyFiles@2 - Copy files v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml)

> Use the path separator that matches your build agent type. For example, / must be used for Linux agents.

When using Linux Agents, we need to use `/` in the file path.

You can change the `\` to `/` in your task definition. `/` character is also work for Windows Agent.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    Contents: |
      $(projWinConsoles)/bin/Release/**
      $(projWinConsoles)/**/*.ico
    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WPF
```

Comment: I will try to change path separator, but i'm using a Windows SelfHosted Agent

Comment: You can try it and feel free to share the result. I test this sample in windows agent and it can work too

Comment: On the other hand, you can also check if the variable: `$(projWinConsoles)`  contains special characters. You can try to hardcode the path in the copy files content and check if it can work.

Comment: @JuanDYB Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I have mark your reply as answer. With regards,